# PyCharm: How to tell if previously sent selection has completed execution at console?

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I use `Alt`+`Shift`+`E` to send a selection of code from the editor to the (IPython) console. But, I am not able to tell when the code has completed executing, since the next prompt appears even though the previous code chunk might not have completed executing. So:

- Either I have to try and send another selection to the console, and the editor warns me that the previous command has not completed running, or,
- I have to try and enter something at the console, and if the results of the requested computation are not returned (`print 2 + 2`, say), then I know that the previous command has not completed execution.

Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:
[image]

**Am I missing some feature that tells me that a selection sent to the console has not completed executing?**

As an example, `R` will not show the next prompt until one chunk has finished execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is now resolved in the latest builds of PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15727). Thanks to JetBrains for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a pycharm feature, but your `print` statements will execute after the previous code is finished running, in a way, letting you know everything is finished (my programming instructor always would put `print "Ready"` at the end of everything for this reason).

```
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(15)
>>> print "hello"
# 15 seconds later
"hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that defeats the purpose of rapid prototyping quickly sending different chunks of code to the interpreter, without having to append a `print "Ready"` to each block.